# Can I show the whole vertex point on the edge of the grid?

Tags: androidplot

XYPlot vertex points positioned towards the edge of the grid gets cut off and only show the half of the point inside the grid. Can I make it so the whole point is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add some padding to the grid like this:

```
plot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingLeft(PixelUtils.dpToPix(5));
```

you'll probably also want to do the same on the right to keep things symmetrical.

Comment: Are you sure? I have margins added... Source: http://pastebin.com/4h7RN6te , Result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1y4o8p5agqzbyd4/test.png

Comment: Whoops I misspoke - it's actually gridPaddingLeft.  Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you! GridPadding did it! :-)